# reserved keywords like CON, PRN, NUL in URL in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, operating-system

I tried to hit URL with id as CON in ASP.net MVC.

Routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }// Parameter defaults              
        );
```

Its giving following error

```
2015-04-29 08:25:22,325 [8] FATAL Myapplication.Global - Application ERROR === (null)
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005)
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetPhysicalPath(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData()
   at System.Web.HttpContext.GetRuntimeConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpContext.get_ImpersonationToken()
   at System.Web.ClientImpersonationContext.Start(HttpContext context, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
```

Comment: http://localhost/Administration/Users/Edit/CON

Comment: That url is NOT mapped by the default route. Can you please add details about which controller and action you want to handle this request?

Comment: Administration is area UsersController is controller Edit is action CON is id

Comment: @Leo this URL is actually mapped by the default route but id portion of it is "Edit"

Comment: I am not getting error for other id like ABC, localhost/Administration/Users/Edit/ABC its working fine. problem is with CON only. I guess its because CON is reserved keyword of windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are couple of reserved keywords like CON, PRN, NUL, and others (these were left in Windows OS family for backwards compatibility I believe). Just add to your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>
     ......
</system.web>
```

It should fix the issue.